# Jetty JNDI - How to specify 'auth', 'type', and factory in one place

Tags: jetty, jndi

I'm looking to get Camunda (BMP engine) working in Jetty by using their working tomcat as an example.

Tomcat's JNDI for a needed resource is in its server.xml (independent of specific web app) as follows:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="global/camunda-bpm-platform/process-engine/ProcessEngineService!org.camunda.bpm.ProcessEngineService"
        auth="Container"
        type="org.camunda.bpm.ProcessEngineService"
        description="camunda BPM platform Process Engine Service"
     factory="org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jndi.ProcessEngineServiceObjectFactory" />
```

When doing this in jetty, I didn't see a place to put all of this info in a single entry, outside of  a web app.  It looks like I have to create the naming entry in, for example, jetty.xml and then, to add the 'type' and the 'auth', I have to add a  entry in web.xml of my camunda engine web app (there are 2 of them).  Is this correct?  E.g.

jetty.xml:

```
Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.Server">
    <New id="cf" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg><Ref refid="Server"/></Arg>
        <Arg>global/camunda-bpm-platform/process-engine/ProcessEngineService!org.camunda.bpm.ProcessEngineService</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jndi.ProcessEngineServiceObjectFactory"></New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

and then in WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>camunda/pe</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>org.camunda.bpm.ProcessEngineService</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Is there another way?

Bill

Comment: Have you seen this? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/camunda-bpm-users/TWue3p0duOM